# Need help with a problem regarding normal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

can someone help me with the following question?

---

Suppose $\mathbf{T}_i (i=1,2,...,n)$ are all $n\times n$ Hermitian positive semi-definite matrices satisfying: $\mathbf{T}_i\ne\mathbf{T}_j$ and $\mathbf{T}_i\ne\mathbf{0}$. Construct the following two matrices:
$\mathbf{T}=\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf{T}_i$ and $\mathbf{\Omega}=\sum_{i=1}^n \gamma_i\mathbf{T}_i$, where $\gamma_i$ are arbitrary complex numbers. Then in order for $\mathbf{T}^{-\frac{1}{2}}\mathbf{\Omega}\mathbf{T}^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ to be normal, what should $\mathbf{T}_i$ look like?

---

Actually, I can prove that if $\mathbf{T}_i$ are all rank-1 Hermitian positive semi-definite matrices, then $\mathbf{T}^{-\frac{1}{2}}\mathbf{\Omega}\mathbf{T}^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ is normal. It appears that if $\mathbf{T}_i$ are all diagonal matrix, the same is also true. I am just wondering if there is any other form that will do the work? Or there are only these two cases...

Thanks a lot for this.

Answer (score 2):

It is not necessary that $\mathbf{T}_i$ are rank one for $\mathbf{T}^{-1/2}\mathbf{\Omega}\mathbf{T}^{-1/2}$ to be normal. Consider $\mathbf{T}_i$ to be diagonal with real non-negative entries.

Comment: But sorry I miss to mention in my original post that \T_i should not be zero matrices (I have corrected it now) and so this actually precludes the example in 2). As for 1), I don't think \Omega is Hermitian under the given conditions. Especially please note that \T_i are Hermitian and \gamma_i are complex numbers. Hence \Omega=\sum_i{\gamma_i T_i} is not equal to its complex transpose.

Comment: @maycui I see, sorry I missed that. However, the rank-one condition still does not seem to be necessary since you can consider all $\mathbf{T}_i$'s to be arbitrary diagonal matrices (with real non-negative diagonal entries to be HPSD). Then everything is diagonal and hence normal. I've edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: I think your example is correct. $\mathbf{T}_i$ indeed does not have to be single-rank for the normality to hold. Anyway, I am wondering if there is a general answer to this question, that is: what should $\mathbf{T}_i$ generally look like in order for the constructed matrix to be normal? According to your example, diagonal matrix will do the work. And single-rank matrix will also do. Is there any other form